# Display Program message in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to upload the batch in AS400 but unable to upload successfully because of Display program message screen appearing after submitting that.
Can you please help me on this what needs to done to avoid display program messages screen

Error Message : [image]

Comment: You assume knowledge about your environment in us readers we don't have. Please rephrase your question. Add details about from where and how (used applications/functions within) you "upload the batch". What exactly do you do by "uploading"? What does the batch contain? And how is your screen display related to the "batch upload" connection to the machine? In addition, whatever gets started fails: The screen shot shows an error message. IWS1611 hints to you using CPYFRMPCD. Did you answer D and had a look at the spooled output in the QEZDEBUG output queue?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be programming related.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options depending on how you submit the job.

You can use system reply list entries (ADDRPYLE), if it's a CL you can monitor message (MONMSG).

However, as was mentioned previously you'll need to review the joblog to see why the file wasn't copied successfully.

In a CL you can you MONMSG to trap/catch the error and allow the job to continue, and/or notify via e-mail (SNDSMTPEMM).

Comment: Similarly, in an RPG ILE program you can catch the error with a `MONITOR` statement, but the real fix is to learn to use `F1` to explore the message details in the job log and understand what the system is telling you.

Comment: In case it's not clear, it took me longer than it should have to realize that you must **put the cursor on the message** and hit `F1`.  That alone unlocks much information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an informal message. Which says PC-File not copied. (`wrkMsgF qIwsMsg`) Please provide a joblog as ordered in the message to get further advice.